# How to "fuzzy match" large data sets about people efficiently in Oracle or?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, bigdata

So we have two tables in the database (Oracle):

- Table A (~15 million rows)
- Table B (~250k rows)

Table B is small enough that we could fit it in memory, Table A is not.

The data is "bad", inconsistent, unstructured. Names and addresses may be spelled incorrectly or differently, with abbreviations, etc.

To be considered a match, there are various criteria, that all boils down to this:

`(A AND B AND C) AND (X OR Y OR Z)`

The worst approach is the brute force, **n^2** approach of comparing everything in Table A to Table B.

Considering that would be **~3.75 trillion** operations, that's not really an option for us, given constraints in our infrastructure. That is to say, we couldn't parallelize something of this scale today.

So, what are some alternative approaches in the database itself or in memory?

Again we could fit everything in Table B in memory, but I'm not sure there is any advantage to bringing this outside of the database.

Comment: what's your dbms?

Comment: Good old Oracle, I edited the post to include that

Comment: What is your server capacity; CPU, IO bandwidth, memory, database version?

Comment: I may be suggesting the obvious, but why not make function-based indexes on all variants of  (A AND B AND C) AND (X OR Y OR Z) ?

Comment: 16 cores, 10GB of memory and the disk is not an SSD. Sadly that's one of the bulkier production environments.

Comment: @wolfrevokcats the main challenge is there are two problems we have to solve. One is the scale issue, which could normally be solved by basic indeces. But the challenge is that A, B, C, X, Y and Z are all much larger conditions than they appear in this simplified form. That is to say that there are many conditions that make up each of A to Z. A considerable amount of normalization will need to occur before we even attempt this matching, and even then we will be left with misspellings and abbreviations that we need to attempt to match to something on the other side.

Comment: You could run these as separate queries and union the results together. That may be the best approach. Taking the elephant down one leg at a time...